# Ошибка выполнения процедуры

Tags: sqldeveloper

[image: Ошибка в процедуре?]

Можете подсказать, что означает красный крест рядом с процедурой?

Comment: как вариант процедура не валидна. Это может происходит если вы изменяете структуру таблицы при этом проседура остаётся старой

Comment: Спасибо! А как можно увидеть, на что ругается процедура?

Comment: Возьмите код и запустите снова

Comment: Без запуска никак не выйдет посмотреть, на что ругается? Просто она достаточно много ресурсов ест, архив логи могут переполниться.

Comment: Ну тогда анализ, самому сделать каждой команды в процедуре

Comment: Кликните на процедуру, там будет вкладка - "Errors".

Comment: Там было пусто. Но крестик оставался, пришлось пересоздавать, чтобы пропал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[По этой ссылке](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/sqldev/r30/plsql_debug_OBE/plsql_debug_otn.htm) следующая информация:

> Note that when an invalid PL/SQL subprogram is detected by Oracle SQL Developer, the status is indicated with a red X over the icon for the subprogram in the Connections Navigator.

Обратите внимание, что при обнаружении недопустимой подпрограммы PL/SQL Oracle SQL статус отображается красным крестиком над значком подпрограммы в навигаторе подключений.